# How to convert PEM file to PPK using PuTTYgen in Ubuntu

Tags: amazon-web-services, putty, private-key, pem, key-pair

I have created an EC2 instance on AWS. I want to connect to the instance using PuTTY, but it requires PPK file. I have PEM file which I want to covert into PPK using PuTTYgen.

How do I use PuTTYgen on Ubuntu to convert PEM file to PPK?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

With *nix version of PuTTYgen:

```
puttygen mykey.pem -o mykey.ppk
```

See [PuTTYgen man page](https://manpages.debian.org/stable/putty-tools/puttygen.1.en.html).

*On Ubuntu, you can install the PuTTY package with `sudo apt install putty-tools`.*

---

For Windows users: Note that Windows version of PuTTYgen does not support key conversions from command-line.

You can use [WinSCP with the `/keygen` command-line switch instead to convert the key](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/commandline#keygen), like:

```
winscp.com /keygen mykey.pem /output=mykey.ppk
```

For compatibility with PuTTYgen, WinSCP also supports its syntax:

```
winscp.com /keygen mykey.pem -o mykey.ppk
```

Answer (score 6):

Do you need Putty to connect to your instance's command line? You mentioned you use Ubuntu, so you can use PEM key with plain ssh:

```
ssh -i mykey.pem user@hostname
```

Comment: Thanks so much, i can now able to access AWS via command prompt in windows machine.